# Prove a simple property of Lebesgue integrals

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Given $B \subset A$, can we prove that $\int_{B} fdp < \int_{A}fdp$? If yes how? What assumptions should be made in order for the inequality to be true? Intuitively it makes sense to me, because it's like integrating a smaller area (loosely speaking)  but I could not find any known property covering this case. Thank you.

Comment: If $f$ is negative you could have a problem. If $f \geq 0$, no problem : note that $\int_X fdp = \int_{\Omega} f1_{X} dp$ for $X \subset \Omega$ the sample space, and use monotonicity.

Comment: I guess then that if I impose $f>0$ I am fine, right? I'm requiring a strictly positive $f$ since if I understood correctly the answer of Darsen it may fail for $f=0$, correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Ooh I did not see the strict sign : yes imposing $f >0$ and requiring $p(A \setminus B) > 0$ is sufficient.

Comment: Thank you again!

Comment: Welcome, kolmogorovwannabe !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that for you $B\subset A$ means $B\subsetneq A$.

As a trivial counterexample you could consider the zero function. In general the inequality doesn't have to be true because you could have $\displaystyle\int_{A\setminus B}f\,\text{d}p=0$.

As Teresa Lisbon rightly pointed out in the comments, you would have the inequality if $f>0$ on $A\setminus B$ and $A\setminus B$ is a set of positive measure, i.e., $p(A\setminus B)>0$, since then $\displaystyle\int_{A\setminus B}f\,\text{d}p>0$ ([the Lebesgue integral of a positive function on a set of positive measure is positive](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1123943/lebesgue-integral-of-a-positive-function-on-a-set-of-positive-measure#:%7E:text=Lebesgue%20integral%20of%20a%20positive%20function%20on%20a%20set%20of%20positive%20measure,-measure%2Dtheory%20lebesgue&text=Let%20E%20be%20a%20subset,for%20all%20x%E2%88%88E.)). Therefore $\displaystyle\int_A f\,\text{d}p=\int_{A\setminus B}f\,\text{d}p+\int_Bf\,\text{d}p>\int_Bf\,\text{d}p$

Comment: So, if I understood correctly, if I impose $f>0$ the inequality is always true? with $B \subset A$ I mean exactly a proper subset. Something such as $A=[0,0.5]$, $B=[0,0.3]$ and $f$ strictly positive could be a good example to apply the property, right? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, but I forgot to add that you need $A\setminus B$ to be of positive measure, or otherwise you would have $\int_{A\setminus B}f\,\text{d}p=0$. I added it already.

Comment: Does this answers your question?

Comment: Absolutely, before voting for the best answer could you please add that the proof of Teresa Lisbon is fine? In this way future readers will have the complete picture: intuition + a proof. Thank you.

Comment: Ok. I added a reference too.