# How do I prove this statement about integrable function when f(x)>0 for almost all x?

Tags: integration

I have the following problem:

> Let $f$ be an integrable function such that $f(x)>0$ for $\mu$-almost all x. Prove that for every $A=\mathcal{A}$ with $\mu(A)>0$ we have $\int_{A} f\,d\mu>0$

I wanted to prove it like this:

**Proof**
We remark that $f(x)>0$ for $\mu$-almost all x is equivalent to say that the set $\Omega_{\leq 0}=\{x\in \Omega|f(x)\leq 0\}$ is a null set, i.e. $\mu(\Omega_{\leq 0})=0$. Let $A\in \mathcal{A}$ such that $\mu(A)>0$. then $$\int_A f\,d\mu=\int_{\Omega_{\leq 0}} f\,d\mu+\int_{A\setminus \Omega_{\leq 0}} f\,d\mu$$ Since $\mu(\Omega_{\leq 0})=0 \Rightarrow \int_{\Omega_{\leq 0}} f\,d\mu=0$.
Therefore $$\int_A f\,d\mu=\int_{A\setminus \Omega_{\leq 0}} f\,d\mu$$ Now let us look at $A\setminus \Omega_{\leq 0}=\{x\in A|f(x)>0\}$. Since $\mu(A)>0$, i.e. A is not a null set, we know that $A\setminus \Omega_{\leq 0}\neq \emptyset$.Therefore we can find $x$ such that  $\forall x\in A\setminus \Omega_{\leq 0}$ we have $f(x)>0$ $$\Rightarrow \int_{A\setminus \Omega_{\leq 0}} f\,d\mu>\int_{A\setminus \Omega_{\leq 0}} 0\,d\mu =0$$

Does this work like this?

If not I would appreciate it that we can fix it together, i.e. use the parts which are correct in my solution and fix the other parts instead of giving me a whole new solution.

Thank you a lot!

Comment: You probably meant $\int_{A\setminus \Omega_{\leq 0}} f\,d\mu>\int_{A\setminus \Omega_{\leq 0}} 0\,d\mu  =0$. However, that inequality is the crucial part, see for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1123943/42969 for a complete proof.

Comment: Yes perfect, but would the rest work like this?