# How may you show that the multivariable integral of a positive function is also positive?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, indefinite-integrals, contour-integration

I have a question on the concept of multivariable integration of positive functions, which may be of great interest to those that subscribe to the mathematics stack exchange.

It should be remarked that I have also searched and read previous posts from this mathematics stack exchange. However, these did not help me with the questions to be presented here. Since multivariable calculus is a great topic here, I believe these questions, along with their possible discussions and answers, may be of great interest to those that subscribe to the mathematics stack exchange.

With that said, it is well-known that if a function $f(x)$ is non-negative (non-postive), then its integral is non-negative (non-positive). More precisely, let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be an integrable positive function, then
$\int^{a}_{b}f(x)dx>0$.

With this result in mind, suppose that we have the following integral

$$I=\int \int \left(\nabla\times\vec{F}\right)\cdot d\vec{A}=\int \int dxdy\left(\frac{\partial F_{2}}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial F_{1}}{\partial y}\right).$$
Based on the above, I ask:

1. If

$$\left(\frac{\partial F_{2}}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial F_{1}}{\partial y}\right)>0$$,

would that imply that $I>0$?

2. Is there any reference in which this result is discussed or demonstrated?

Comment: " which may be of great interest to those that subscribe to the mathematics stack exchange." 
Don't worry, this is not a journal, you don't have to justify being in the scopes.
Usually.

Comment: Anyway, notice that $\int\int G(x,y) dxdy = \int(\int G(x,y) dy)dx$ when $G$ is nonnegative by Fubini-Tonelli Theorem. As a consequence you can apply the rule you mentioned 1 dimension at a time

Comment: It is true without reference to Fubini. Just apply basic Riemann sum or Lebesgue sum definitions of integral. A limit of positive quantities is positive.

Comment: Well, except the limit of $1/n$ is $0$ as $n$ grows.

Comment: @Randall Sure, it was poorly worded. But e.g. with Lebesgue integration the limits involved are monotonic. I guess I was assuming continuity of the integrand to really make that work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only if the set you are integrating over has nonzero area. For example if $F(\boldsymbol x)>0$ then
$$\int\limits_{|\boldsymbol x|<1}F(\boldsymbol x)\mathrm d^2\boldsymbol x>0$$
Because the set
$$\{\boldsymbol x\in\Bbb R^2:|\boldsymbol x|<1\}$$
Has positive area. On the other hand,
$$\int\limits_{x_1\in[0,1]~,~x_2=0}F(\boldsymbol x)\mathrm d^2\boldsymbol x=0\tag{1}$$
Since the set
$$\{(x_1,x_2)\in\Bbb R^2:x_1\in[0,1]~\text{and}~x_2=0\}$$
Has zero area.

---

This essentially comes down to *how you measure sets*. If considered the same integral as equation $(1)$, but integrated with respect to the measure $\mathrm dx_1$ instead of the measure $\mathrm d^2\boldsymbol x$ we would get
$$\int\limits_{x_1\in[0,1]~,~x_2=0}F(x_1,x_2)\mathrm dx_1 \\ =\int_0^1 F(x_1,0)\mathrm dx_1>0$$
Because now the set
$$\{(x_1,x_2)\in\Bbb R^2:x_1\in[0,1]~\text{and}~x_2=0\}$$
Has *positive measure* with respect to the measure $\mathrm dx_1$.

---

Generally speaking, let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a [measure space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_space) and let $f:X\to\Bbb R_+$ be integrable and everywhere positive. Let $E\in\Sigma$ be a measurable set. The following hold:

- If $\mu(E)=0$, then $\int_E f~\mathrm d\mu=0$.
- If $\mu(E)\neq 0$, then $\int_E f~\mathrm d\mu >0$.

See for instance [this MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1123943/lebesgue-integral-of-a-positive-function-on-a-set-of-positive-measure) for proof.

Comment: I hope you are doing well. Thanks for the answer. It helped me. Nonetheless, I have an additional doubt based on your answer. If $F(x)$ may have negative values, does $\int_{|x|<1}F(\textbf{x})d\textbf{x}^{2} >0$ still hold?

Comment: @V1999 In that case, no. For instance, take $F(\boldsymbol x)=-1$. Then
$$\int_{|\boldsymbol x|<1}F(\boldsymbol x)\mathrm d^2\boldsymbol x=-\pi<0.$$